# Webpack — When building a code bundle, and subsequently importing it, how do I access named exports?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ckeditor, webpack-4

I’m building a custom version of CKEditor which uses webpack (v4) to bundle the src into a minified bundle. My src includes both default and named exports, along the lines of:

```js
export default class MyEditor extends ClassicEditor {}
export class InteractiveMyEditor extends ClassicEditor {}
export const Context = CKContext
```

The `webpack.config.js` file includes the following `output` section

```js
output: {
  library: 'MyEditor',
  path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'build' ),
  filename: 'ckeditor.js',
  libraryTarget: 'umd',
  libraryExport: 'default'
},
```

it all builds fine and I can

```js
import MyEditor from '@project/ckeditor-build-myeditor'
// MyEditor is defined
```

just fine.

But I can't access the `InteractiveMyEditor` or the `Context` objects

```js
import { Context, InteractiveMyEditor } from '@project/ckeditor-build-myeditor'
// both Context and InteractiveMyEditor are undefined
```

I've been trying to make sense of the Webpack4 Docs but can't see what else to do other than try different values for `libraryTarget`.  I've tried `commonjs`, and `'module` just to see if that helped but alas no.

How do I export the named exports correctly?